# Fortranでフォルダの選択ダイアログを表示する方法について

Tags: windows, fortran

Fortranを用いてWindowsのフォルダの選択ダイアログを表示する方法を探しております。使用環境はIntelコンパイラになります。ExamplesのGetOpenFileNameなどの例を参考にしようとしておりましたが、現状でフォルダを選択して閉じるダイアログを表示する方法の検討もついておりません。
どなたか本件に関してお知恵をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたら、お知恵を拝借したく存じます。何卒、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！ 参考にしようとした例があるとのことですが、なるべく広い範囲の人に興味を持ってもらうために、そのサンプルプログラムへのリンク等を貼ると良いかもしれません。自分の質問は自由に編集できますので、お試しください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

補足：
フルパスが採れるようにしたから、編集の仕方がよく分からないので付け足しておく。
（前回は夜中に寝ながら書いたので、日本語もおかしくてすまんかった。許してたもれ。）

WIN32 API 引数のポインタは、番地は固定なので intent(in) にした。（内容的には、in のも out のもあるが･･･）

なお LINKER->入力->追加の依存ファイル の所に  shell32.lib ole32.lib が必要。

```
program folder
  use ifwinty
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS  = Z'00000001'
  integer, parameter :: BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN = Z'00000002'
  ! 以下略

  type :: t_browseinfo  
    sequence
    integer(HANDLE) :: hwndOwner = NULL               !// 親ウィンドウのハンドル
    integer(LPINT)  :: pidlRoot  = NULL               !// ルートにする場所を指定。
    integer(LPSTR)  :: pszDisplayName                 !// 選択されたフォルダ名（フルパスではない）が格納される。
    integer(LPCSTR) :: lpszTitle                      !// ダイアログに表示するメッセージ
    integer(UINT)   :: ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS !// どのフォルダを選択させるかのオプション
    integer(UINT)   :: lpfn = NULL                    !// 
    integer(HANDLE) :: lParam = 0                     !// 
    integer         :: iImage = 0                     !//  
  end type t_browseinfo
  type(t_browseinfo) :: test

  interface
    integer function SHBrowseForFolder(t)
      !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DEFAULT, STDCALL, DECORATE, ALIAS:'SHBrowseForFolder' :: SHBrowseForFolder
      import
      integer(LPINT), intent(in) :: t
    end function SHBrowseForFolder

    integer function SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, pszPath)
      !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DEFAULT, STDCALL, DECORATE, ALIAS:'SHGetPathFromIDList' :: SHGetPathFromIDList
      import
      integer(LPINT), intent(in) :: pidl
      integer(LPINT), intent(in) :: pszPath
    end function SHGetPathFromIDList

    integer function CoTaskMemFree(pv)
      !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DEFAULT, STDCALL, DECORATE, ALIAS:'CoTaskMemFree' :: CoTaskMemFree
      import
      integer(LPINT), intent(in) :: pv
    end function CoTaskMemFree
  end interface

  character(len = *), parameter :: msg = "選べ！"C
  character(len = 512) :: buff, path
  integer(LPINT) :: status
  integer(BOOL)  :: iret
! 
  test%lpszTitle = loc(msg)
  test%pszDisplayName = loc(buff)
  status = SHBrowseForFolder(loc(test))
!  print *, 'status=', status
  if (status /= 0) then
    iret = SHGetPathFromIDList(status, loc(path))
    print *, path(:index(path, ""C))
    print *, buff(:index(buff, ""C))
    iret = CoTaskMemFree(status)
  else
    print *, '--no folder was selected--'
  end if  
end program folder
```

Comment: 反応が遅れて申し訳ありません。
はじめに教えて頂いたコードからフルパスを読めるように書き換えようとして詰まっておりましたところでした。
フルパス版も挙げて頂きましてありがとうございました。大変参考になります。

Answer (score 2):

フォルダー選択ダイアログは Intel の提供するインターフェースに存在しないので、自分で必要な定数やインターフェースを定義すれば何とかなる。ネットでググると出てくる C による win32 API をコピペしてきて、Fortran用に書き直せばよい。しかし定数等も自分で定義しないと駄目なのでだるい。整数のバイト数の宣言はどうせ４または８なので適当に書いておけば大抵は何とかなる。

あと、shell32.libをリンカのところに付け足しておく必要がある。

以下の例では、コンソールアプリケーションから、フォルダー選択のダイアログが開いて、何か選択するとその名前が出る。フルパス名は、返り値を別の関数APIに入れてゲットできるようだが、めんどくさいので自分で何とかしてくれｗ

```
program folder
  use ifwinty
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS  = Z'00000001'
  integer, parameter :: BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN = Z'00000002'
  ! 以下略

  character(len = *), parameter :: buf = "選べ！"C
  type :: t_browseinfo  
    sequence
    integer(HANDLE) :: hwndOwner = NULL               !// 親ウィンドウのハンドル
    integer(LPINT)  :: pidlRoot  = NULL               !// ルートにする場所を指定。
    integer(LPSTR)  :: pszDisplayName                 !// 選択されたフォルダ名（フルパスではない）が格納される。
    integer(LPCSTR) :: lpszTitle                      !// ダイアログに表示するメッセージ
    integer(UINT)   :: ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS !// どのフォルダを選択させるかのオプション
    integer(UINT)   :: lpfn = NULL                    !// 
    integer(HANDLE) :: lParam = 0                     !// 
    integer :: iImage = 0                             !//  
  end type t_browseinfo
  type(t_browseinfo) :: test

  interface
    integer function SHBrowseForFolder(t)
      !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DEFAULT, STDCALL, DECORATE, ALIAS:'SHBrowseForFolder' :: SHBrowseForFolder
      import
      integer(LPINT) :: t
    end function
  end interface

  character(len = 512) :: buff
  integer:: status
! 
  test%lpszTitle = loc("選べ！"C)
  test%pszDisplayName = loc(buff)
  status = SHBrowseForFolder(loc(test))
  print *, 'status=', status
  print *, buff(:index(buff, ""C))
end program folder
```